# Unable to track an entity of type 'Entity' because its primary key property 'Id' is null

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
public clase Book
{
  [Key]
  public string Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  ...
}
_dbContext.Books.Add(new Entity(){
   Name="C#10.0",
   ....
})
_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Exception message:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'Book' because its primary key property 'Id' is null.

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)

```
When I use this DatabaseGeneratedAttribte, after assigning a value to the primary key in the application, call "SaveChanges()" an exception will be thrown and the trace will be modified.
```

I expect this value to prevail after assigning a value to the primary key. If it is not assigned, the value can be automatically generated.

Comment: EntityFromeworkCore>=5.0 and 
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql >= 5.0

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. `string` properties are **not** auto-generated by default. If you want to make it auto-generated, then use the attribute or fluent API to configure that. Then by idea if you provide PK value, then it will be used, otherwise will be auto-generated. So, with what you have shown its normally to get such exception since the PK is not auto-generated, so you can omit that from the question. What's is the exact problem with using attribute?

Comment: You understand exactly what I think，The problem as follows
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database 
operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32

Comment: Hmm, do you have some fluent configuration, for instance `HasDefaultValueSql` for that property? The problem is that auto-generation could be client side or database side. And EF `INSERT` command behavior depends on that. Have to look what does Pomelo for auto-generated strings - normally they are auto-generated client side with new `Guid` converted to string.

Comment: The above error is that ValueGeneratedOnAdd is configured. If the configuration can achieve my goal, it will be perfect.I consulted in pomelo. They said it should be efcore. It's terrible。

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Id parameter to be auto generated make sure you apply `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` for that parameter in ModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
            builder.Entity<Book>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            });
}
```

Otherwise, you should assign the Id with a proper value before adding a book entity to DB.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it's not what I expected。
By idea  I provide PK value, then it will be used, otherwise will be auto-generated.